# How do I select a key with a special character in powershell?

Tags: json, powershell

I have a set of key/value pairs that came from a JSON file.

```
$ $p.dependencies

@architect/architect : ^5.7.0
@architect/functions : ^3.0.4
assert               : ^1.4.1
bcrypt               : ^3.0.6
find-parent-dir      : ^0.3.0
hashids              : ^1.2.2
http-status-codes    : ^1.3.2
lodash.get           : ^4.4.2
mini-web-server      : ^1.0.2
mini-webhook-server  : ^1.0.4
mocha                : ^5.2.0
opencorporates       : ^3.0.0
stripe               : ^6.23.1
uuid                 : ^3.3.2
whois-json           : ^2.0.4
```

Looks like in Powershell they're `noteProperty`s:

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name                 MemberType   Definition
----                 ----------   ----------
Equals               Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode          Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType              Method       type GetType()
ToString             Method       string ToString()
@architect/architect NoteProperty string @architect/architect=^5.7.0
@architect/functions NoteProperty string @architect/functions=^3.0.4
assert               NoteProperty string assert=^1.4.1
bcrypt               NoteProperty string bcrypt=^3.0.6
find-parent-dir      NoteProperty string find-parent-dir=^0.3.0
hashids              NoteProperty string hashids=^1.2.2
http-status-codes    NoteProperty string http-status-codes=^1.3.2
lodash.get           NoteProperty string lodash.get=^4.4.2
mini-web-server      NoteProperty string mini-web-server=^1.0.2
mini-webhook-server  NoteProperty string mini-webhook-server=^1.0.4
mocha                NoteProperty string mocha=^5.2.0
opencorporates       NoteProperty string opencorporates=^3.0.0
stripe               NoteProperty string stripe=^6.23.1
uuid                 NoteProperty string uuid=^3.3.2
whois-json           NoteProperty string whois-json=^2.0.4
```

**I would like to change the item with a key of `@architect/functions` to a value different from `^3.0.4` (an then save the data back out)**

The next part of that seems to be selecting the right item from the hashtable. I am using:

```
$p.dependencies | where $_.key -eq "@architect/functions"
```

However this returns no results. **How can I select the item with the key `@architect/functions`?** For bonus points, how can I change the value!

**Edit**:

Using the answer, here's my final script if anyone finds it useful.

```
ls 'src/http' | foreach { 
    $packageJSONFile = "${PSItem}\package.json" 
    $packageJSON = cat $packageJSONFile | convertfrom-json
    if ( $packageJSON.dependencies.'@architect/functions'  ) {
        $packageJSON.dependencies.'@architect/functions' = '^3.0.4'
    }   
    $packageJSON | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100| set-content $packageJSONFile
}
```

Comment: $p.dependencies.’@architect/functions’= somevalue should update it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a property with special characters in the name, quote it:

```
$p.dependencies.'@architect/functions'
```

Answer (score 4):

[Tomalak's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55768173/45375) solves your problem.

**As for your attempt** to use `where` (`Where-Object`) to retrieve the property of interest:

> `$p.dependencies | where $_.key -eq "@architect/functions"`

There are two fundamental problems:

- In the abstract, using [*simplified syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) (that is, using *individual arguments* instead of a *script block*) requires you to use property names *alone* (`key`), not via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) (`$_.key`)

  - In fact, **`$_`** - to refer to the pipeline input object at hand - is **only ever meaningful *inside a script block* (`{ ... }`)**.
  - That is, if your command were otherwise correct (it isn't, see below), you'd have to use:
    `$p.dependencies | where key -eq '@architect/functions'`
- As your output shows, `$p.dependencies` contains a `[pscustomobject]` instance, not a hash table (`[hashtable]`); `ConvertFrom-Json` returns `[pscustomobject]` instances, unless you explicitly request hash tables with the **`-AsHashtable`** switch.

  - If it were a hash table, PowerShell would send it through the pipeline *as a whole*.
  - In order to send a hash table's *entries* one by one through the pipeline, you'd have to call `.GetEnumerator()` on it, which would allow you to filter by their `Key` property.